# Pass File Validation Constraint to generic FileType entity

Tags: php, validation, constraints, symfony

I'm creating a bundle which have a file reference object which has no constraints on itself because it will be a generic object. It might store images or any other type of file and I need to keep it as generic as possible.

Other bundle is using my FileType reference and I need to assign the file validation to this object through constraint. How would I force the file validation on the referenced file object?

The Generic FileType:

```
namespace ICC\FileCabinetBundle\Form;

use ICC\FileCabinetBundle\Entity\FileRef;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Comment form.
 */
class FileCabinetType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class, [
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'required' => false
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FileRef::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The Entity that is calling my generic FileType, and I need it to validate this generic entity into image validation. Notice that my attempt of creating a constraint does not work there, but it would if I would insert it into my generic object.

```
namespace ICC\UserBundle\Form;

use ICC\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use ICC\FileCabinetBundle\Form\FileCabinetType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

/**
 * User Profile form.
 */
class UserProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fileRef', FileCabinetType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'box__file'],
                'label' => 'form.profile.edit.file_ref',
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '2048k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/jpeg',
                            'image/png'
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'icc_filecabinet.file.mime'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, ['label' => 'form.profile.edit.first_name'])
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, ['label' => 'form.profile.edit.last_name'])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'form.profile.edit.submit']);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html